# @PostMapping doesn't work: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'XXX' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to `thymeleaf` and `Spring-Boot`, I followed this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) to create a submit form I made exactly the same thing,  but I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'conjugation' available as request attribute
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code, knowing that this is my `Conjugation` class

```
public class Conjugation {
    private String v;

    public String getV() {
        return this.v;
    }

    public void setV(String v) {
        this.verb = v;
    }

}
```

This is what I used in my controller

```
//The Controller
@GetMapping("/conjugate")
  public String vForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("conjugate", new Conjugation());
    return "conjugate";
  }

@PostMapping("/conjugate")
  public String vbSubmit(@ModelAttribute Conjugation conjugate) {
    System.out.println("-->"+conjugate.getV());
    return "index";
  }
```

And this my `index.html` file:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/conjugate}" th:object="${conjugation}" method="post">
    <div class="cell">
        V
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input class="cell" type="text"  th:field="*{v}" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @MiraSoft just replace the `th:object="${conjugation}"`  object with  `conjugate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the attribute named as `conjugate`:

```java
model.addAttribute("conjugate", new Conjugation());
```

but in your html file you say `conjugation`

```html
th:object="${conjugation}"
```

This will work if you replace your current `model.addAttribute`, with:

```java
model.addAttribute("conjugation", new Conjugation());
```